# How do I config tunnels in netplan

Tags: netplan, tunnel

I cant find any docs on how to bring up tunnels with netplan.  Can some point me to the correct docs or does netplan not manage tunnels?

Comment: See [here](https://netplan.io/examples)

Answer (score 0):

As of netplan 0.40.2.1, there is currently no support for managing tunnels.  For the time being you will want to continue managing tunnels using `/etc/network/interfaces`.